# FullCalendar refetchEvents not reloading calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, fullcalendar

If an ajax call to create a new event succeeds, I would like to reload this pages fullcalendar. However, calling refetchEvents seems to have absolutely no effect - and watching the network traffic in chrome shows that no call is being made to the URL where fullcalendar queries events. What am I missing?

```
function submitNewEvent(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        dnnEvent = dnnEventWithFormData();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: urlCreateEvent,
            data: dnnEvent
        }).success(function (response) {
            dialog.dialog('close');
            $("#userEvents").load(urlUserEvents);
            $("#calendar").fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
        }).error(function (response) { console.log(response); alert('failed'); });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
var mycal = $("#calendar)....init...
```

then in your `.success`:

```
mycal.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
```