# refetchevents not getting new event

Tags: fullcalendar

I use a function to get my events:

```html
                events: function (start, end, timezone, callback) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '/Controller/GetDiaryEvents/',
                        data: {
```

when I add a new event,   the calendar does not show the newly added event. Do I need to reset my eventsource  somehow ?

```html
                success: function (response) {
                    debugger;
                    if (response == true) {
                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
                        alert('New event saved!');
                      }
```

This link [FullCalendar refetchEvents not reloading calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27321788/fullcalendar-refetchevents-not-reloading-calendar) says to do Calendar..init but I don't see that method.

Comment: based on the code you've shown, there's no reason why it shouldn't work. Have you verified that the event is definitely stored correctly in your database? Does calling "refetchEvents" definitely trigger the ajax call to get the events, or do you get any errors in the console instead? If it fetches the events, does the response contain your new event, or not? Do some basic debugging using your browser tools and your database GUI.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to refetch all events.

When new event is created add it to calendar using [addEventSource](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/addEventSource/) function.

```
$("#calendar").fullCalendar( 'addEventSource', source );
```

> Source may be an Array/URL/Function just as in the events option. Events will be immediately fetched from this source and placed on the calendar.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a function getEvents() and call it where you want to refetch

```
function getEvents()
{
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'refetchEvents' );
}
```